# Make keyboard disappear with textField and textView

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uitextview

I'd like to dismiss the keyboard with a text field using 
`- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {`, but I need to do the same with a text view, so I'll use `- (BOOL)textViewShouldReturn:(UITextView *)textView {`. Is it possible to put them togheter in the same AppDelegate?

Thank you.

Comment: `UITextView` doesn't support a delegate method like the `textFieldShouldReturn:` delegate for `UITextField`. This is because you can enter multiple lines in a text view.

Comment: Just call [yourTextView resignFirstResponder]; from inside your textFieldShouldReturn method.

Comment: @MarkM Why would you call `resignFirstResponder` on a `UITextView` (not `UITextField`) from a delegate method for a `UITextField`?

Comment: rmaddy, because he is wanting to dismiss the keyboard. Calling resignFirstResponder will accomplish this.

Comment: @MarkM You are missing the point. If the `UITextField textFieldShouldReturn:` method is called on the text field then that means the text field is the first responder. Calling `resignFirstResponder` on the text view at this point does nothing. It's fine to resign the text field at this point but not the text view.

Comment: He is asking to do both in one method. Although he calls it an AppDelegate.

Comment: I tried with `[yourTextView resignFirstResponder];` inside `textFieldShouldReturn` but I get an error, and build fails. I think it's because textView is different from textField, so they can't stay togheter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can have two delegates

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate,UITextViewDelegate>
```

### Unfortunately

The protocol UITextViewDelegate **does not have**, something like this.

```
- (BOOL)textViewShouldReturn:(UITextView *)textView {
```

**UITextViewDelegate Protocol**,
[image]

**EDIT 1** :

*Button press event to hide the keyboard.*

```
-(IBAction) yourButtonPressed:(id)sender;{

    for(UIView *v in self.view.subviews){
        if([v isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]] || [v isKindOfClass:[UITextView class]]){
            if([v isFirstResponder]){
                [v resignFirstResponder];
                break;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I copied this into AppDelegate.h without success. Nothing changes.

Comment: I'll do the next time, but unfortunately I've almost finished my app and now I can't "convert" it to ViewControllers; I used Windows instead of ViewControllers, and only AppDelegate.. But never again! It's very inconvenient.

Comment: However, is there a way to give to a button "Done" the function to dismiss the keyboard? It's not necessary to make it as a "tab bar item", it can be a round rect button on the view.

Comment: I updated my answer according to your requirement. Now check.

Comment: Sorry, I get the error message "expected identifier or '('".. I'm going crazy! :(

Comment: Ok, tell me the name your view variable?

Comment: Do you mean the name of text view field? It's `italiano_tesinaField`

Comment: The name of the view (the window) is "view1". The name of the textView is `taliano_tesinaField`

Comment: What are the names of your textField and textView please ?

Comment: Sorry, perhaps I said it wrong. I have no textField, but only a textView (`italiano_tesinaField`) and a round rect button that has to dismiss the keyboard. I need to give the action to this button.

Comment: Oh god !, put this line in that button pressed method. thats all :)  -> if([taliano_tesinaField isFirstResponder]) [taliano_tesinaField resignFirstResponder];

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29505/discussion-between-thilina-hewagama-and-crazysoftware)

Answer (score 0):

Just subscribe to the delegates from your viewController and make sure to set the delegate on those objects to your viewController.

.h

```
@interface YourViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate, UITextViewDelegate>
```

.m

```
someTextField.delegate = self;
someTextView.delegate = self;
```

From the sound of it you just need to tie into the actions of the textField and textView. Create an IBAction and tie it to what you'd like. Then you can resignFirstResponder from that IBAction.

Use this action for both your textField and textView

```
- (IBAction)lowerTheText:(id)sender 
{
    [sender resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: I tried with `@interface YourViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate, UITextViewDelegate>` but I get an error because I'm using Windows, not ViewControllers.

Comment: I say forget the delegate methods and use an IBAction directly. Assign the action to the lowerTheText method.

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand your question...
Basically you will do the following:

- implement the `UITextFieldDelegate` and `UITextViewDelegate` in your
  viewController
- implement the methods of that delegates, you need/want
- resignFirstResponder / endEditing of the textField / textView, where
  ever you want

Answer (score 0):

Yes, with a UITextView it's tricky. As I say in my book...

http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch23.html#_uitextview

...on the iPad, the problem of dismissing the keyboard doesn't arise because the user can dismiss it with the button in the lower right corner of the keyboard. So this leaves only the iPhone. You will typically have an interface such that there is a Done button or similar. Look at how the Notes app solves this, for example.

The process itself is just the same: call `endEditing:` on the superview and whoever is first responder will cease being first responder and the keyboard will retire.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use textfield delegate and textview delegate in the same application.

TextField:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate,UITextViewDelegate>

// This allocates the textfield and sets its frame (or) you can use interfaceBuild
   UITextField *textField = [[UITextField  alloc] initWithFrame:
   CGRectMake(20, 50, 280, 30)]; 

  textField.delegate=self;

// This method enables or disables the processing of return key
-(BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{    
    [textField resignFirstResponder]; // this is event for hide keyboard.
    return YES;
}
```

TextView:

```
// init
 UITextView *textView = [[UITextView  alloc] initWithFrame:
       CGRectMake(20, 50, 280, 30)]; 

 - (void)textViewDidChangeSelection:(UITextView *)textView
{
 [textField resignFirstResponder]; // this is event for hide keyboard.
}
```

Comment: This answer does close the keyboard but after only one letter is entered